# how do i get the biggest and most frequent number in a dictionary?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, tuples

i have a number
`(23452)`
and i what my function to return the most frequent num in this number and the highest one.
for the num above it should return '2' and for '225566' it should return '6'

i tried :

```
def most_popular_digit(num):
pop_dig = {}
c = str(num)
for n in range(len(c)):
    count = pop_dig.get(c[n],0)
    count += 1
    pop_dig[c[n]] = count
list_keys = pop_dig.keys()
sorted_num = sorted(list_keys, key=pop_dig.get)
```

but i cant figure out how to get also the highest number with the highest apperances.

Answer (score 0):

managed to figure it out:

```
def most_popular_digit(num):
pop_dig = {}
c = str(num)
for n in range(len(c)):
    count = pop_dig.get(c[n],0)
    count += 1
    pop_dig[c[n]] = count
list_keys = pop_dig.keys()
sorted_num = sorted(list_keys, key=pop_dig.get)
a = pop_dig.keys()
b = pop_dig.values()
if b.index(max(b)) == a.index(max(a)):
    return a[a.index(max(a))]
else:
    return sorted_num[-1]
```